# yum failed to work if I run some shell commands

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL(Oracle Linux 9.2). If I run some shell commands, then I will not be able to use yum anymore.

For example,

```
$ source scl_source enable gcc-toolset-13
```

Then any yum command will fail and report errors similar as follows:

```
$ sudo yum list
env: ‘Files/WindowsApps/3810OracleAmericaInc.OracleLinux9.2_9.2.0.0_x64__dm28ctvqnhe9g:/mnt/c/Program’: No such file or directory
```

Question> Is there a workaround that I can fix this issues without breaking the yum?

Thank you

Comment: Does `sudo ls` give correct output ?

Comment: I have confirmed the issues is caused by 'source scl_source enable gcc-toolset-13'. However, after I compare the output from `env` with or without this command, I don't know why run this command will cause above issues. 'sudo ls' shows the same errors.

Comment: Can you type `type sudo` and post result ?

Comment: sudo is hashed (/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-13/root/usr/bin/sudo)

Comment: I believe the workaround is simply "/usr/bin/sudo yum list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments, one solution would be to run following command after `source`:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```